# Emberjs - Should attributes in a model all start with a lowercase letter?

Tags: ember.js, model, attributes, attr, lowercase

Should attributes in a model all start with a lowercase letter?

Recently I ran into the issue of having attributes in the model that start with an uppercase letter not work with the "valueBinding=UppercaseAttribute" quality in Ember Handlebars.

I have a *huge* amount of attributes that are going to be changed in the future and I'm wondering if I should just get into the habit of changing them to lowercase now and saving myself a lot of work.

And now the code for all of you visual learners.

So it's this (uppercase)

```
VpcYeoman.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    RecordCategoryID:DS.attr('number'),
    Name: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

***VS***

This (lowercase)

```
VpcYeoman.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    recordCategoryID:DS.attr('number'),
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  By convention, all variable names in *most* languages should be in camel-case, starting with a lowercase character.  Javascript adheres to this convention.

Comment: Thanks! Does this camelCase also apply to dependencies like    
    items: DS.hasMany('items', {async: true})